# Optional chaining in swift with arbitrary operations?

Tags: ios, swift, chaining, option-type

Apple supplies an example of succinct optional chaining

```
class Person {
  var residence: Residence?
}

class Residence {
  var numberOfRooms = 1
}

let john = Person()

if let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms {
  println("John's residence has \(roomCount) room(s).")
} else {
  println("Unable to retrieve the number of rooms.")
}
```

Imagine trying to adjust the condition with some arithmetic operations. This results in a compiler error as the modulo operator doesn't support optionals.

```
if john.residence?.numberOfRooms % 2 == 0 { 
  // compiler error: Value of optional type Int? not unwrapped
  println("John has an even number of rooms")
} else {
  println("John has an odd number of rooms")
}
```

Of course you could always do something like the following, but it lacks the simplicity and succinctness of optional chaining.

```
if let residence = john.residence {
  if residence.numberOfRooms % 2 == 0  {
    println("John has an even number of rooms")
  }else{
    println("John has an odd number of rooms")
  }
} else {
  println("John has an odd number of rooms")
}
```

Are there any Swift language features which might provide a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is generally called a [monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29) in functional programming.

It is not directly available in swift, but by using some of the language features, you can implement monads yourself in a generic way. (And also define a nice looking infix operator that makes it look like the monads in Haskell)

A quick google search for "monad swift" turned up some promising looking code at https://gist.github.com/cobbal/7562875ab5bfc6f0aed6

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is quite powerful, and can work in situations like this:

```
switch john.residence?.numberOfRooms {
case .Some(let x) where x % 2 == 0:
    println("Even number of rooms")
default:
    println("Odd number of rooms")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with is an extension on Optionals called omap (optional map).

```
extension Optional{
  func omap<K:Any>(optionalBlock:(T)->(K?))->K?{
    if self{
      return optionalBlock(self!)
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Similar to map, omap simply returns an instance of the optional to a supplied closure, but handles the nil case appropriately.

This allows you to chain an optional with arbitrary operations like so:

```
if (john.residence.omap{r in r.numberOfRooms % 2 == 0}){
  println("John has an even number of rooms")
} else {
  println("John has an odd number of rooms")
}
```

See: https://gist.github.com/Grantismo/3e1ba0412e911dfd7cfe

Comment: I was under the impression that any answers should be included in the answers section, even if it's provided by the question asker. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. I'm also not convinced my solution is best, so I'm hoping others will provide their ideas.

Comment: Did this even work?  What is T in the extension?  I'm having a hard time getting it to work for myself.

Comment: I could only get `if (john.residence?.numberOfRooms.omap{$0 % 2 == 0}==true)` to compile and run properly.

Comment: @LouFranco My example was wrong, I've updated it accordingly. T is the type of the Optional. In this example the optional is an Optional<Residence>. So `if (john.residence.omap{$0.numberOfRooms % 2 == 0})` works

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want it to say it's even if it's definitely even and odd if it's either odd or any of the optional values aren't set.  If so:

```
if john.residence?.numberOfRooms && (john.residence!.numberOfRooms! % 2) == 0 {
    println("John has an even number of rooms")
} else {
    println("John has an odd number of rooms")
}
```

is the best I could do without a helper function.  The issue is that you need methods to call on optional values to chain.

There are either bugs with if and Bool when optional chaining is being used, or I don't understand it well enough, but this works for me:

```
extension Int{
    func isEven() -> Bool { return self % 2 == 0 }
}

if (john.residence?.numberOfRooms?.isEven() == true){
    println("John has an even number of rooms")
} else {
    println("John has an odd number of rooms")
}
```

If you write

```
if (john.residence?.numberOfRooms?.isEven())
```

That resolves as true as long as numberOfRooms has some value, even if isEven() returns false.  As if the expression was Bool?, but it's not, it's Bool.

Comment: `numberOfRooms` is not an optional is it? This seems to be short and sweet: `if john.residence && john.residence!.numberOfRooms % 2 == 0`

Comment: @JackWu Nice solution. There are some cases where you might want a concise expression of an Int? rather than a Bool?. I couldn't find a better way to express `var numberOfWindows: Int? = john.residence.omap{$0.numberOfRooms * 2}` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use Guard

```
func testOddEven(){
    guard let number = john.residence?.numberOfRooms else {print("Doesn't even have a residence loool"); return }
    switch number % 2 == 0 {
    case true:
        print("event")
        break;
    case false:
        print("odd")
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same thing for the last 10 minutes, using both optional chaining and the nil coalescing operator; the compiler doesn't like either of them. Can be done with an tf/then to get it working, but it feels ugly.

Should be able to do with an extension to Double, though I agree it feels like swift could (should?) support optional chaining in the standard operators. The following works in a playground:

```
extension Double {
  func divide(by: Double) -> Double {
    return (self/by)
  }
}

var optDouble: Double? = nil
var result = optDouble?.divide(by: 100.0)   // nil

optDouble = 20.25
result = optDouble?.divide(by: 100.0)       // 0.2025
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the following line work (i.e. make the operator directly accessing the value behind the optional **left** operand):

```
if john.residence?.numberOfRooms % 2 == 0
```

the operator must be in a precedence-group with `assignment: true`. The modulo operator is in the `MultiplicationPrecedence` precedence-group:

```
precedencegroup MultiplicationPrecedence {
  associativity:left
  higherThan: AdditionPrecedence
}
```

You can make your own prededence-group with `assignment: true`

```
precedencegroup AssignmentTruePrecedence {
    assignment: true
    associativity:left
    higherThan:AdditionPrecedence
    lowerThan:MultiplicationPrecedence
}
```

Now you can declare your own operator, assign it to the above precedence-group, and define the associated function to do the modulo operation.

```
infix operator %| : AssignmentTruePrecedence

extension Int {

    static func %| (left: Int, right: Int)->Int {
        return left % right
    }

}
```

The line will work without error with our new modulo operator:

```
if john.residence?.numberOfRooms %| 2 == 0
```

It turns out that you don't even have to declare a new operator, as redeclaring the modulo operator and assigning it to our new precedence-group seems to work!

```
infix operator % : AssignmentTruePrecedence
```